# For Rayleigh scattering, what is the phase difference between the incident field and the scattered (or reradiated) field?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, scattering

I am asking within the context of electromagnetic theory. Much of the discourse I could find in the literature was more focused on the phase differences between the scattered fields of various particles, rather than the phase difference between the incident and scattered field.

For the case of a single Rayleigh scatterer, is the reradiated field phase-shifted from the incident field?

It's also my understanding that the reradiated fields for the Rayleigh scattering are all in-phase. Is it then safe to assume that there's no dependency between the angle of radiation and phase?